Proof that medians meet using linear dependency
Say I have a triangle with two fixed points $A,B$ and an unknown point $C$. Fixed points are technically linearly dependent of everything, so $A,B$ are linearly dependent on $C$. the midpoint between two linearly dependent points is also linearly dependent, so the midpoints between $A,C$ and $B,C$ are also linearly dependent on $C$. I will call them $B'$ and $A'$ respectively. the lines connecting $B,B'$ and $A,A'$ are also linearly dependent on $C$ because they are the connection of two points linearly dependent on $C$. the intersection between the lines connecting $A,A'$ and $B,B'$ (which I will call $E$) is also linearly dependent on $C$. Once again, I will connect two linearly dependent points (this time $C$ and $E$) to create a line $CE$ that is also linearly dependent on $C$. finally, the intersection between $CE$ and $AB$ (which I will call $C'$) is linearly dependent on $C$. If I now find three non-collinear points $C_{1},C_{2},C_{3}$ for which $C'_{1},C'_{2},C'_{3}$ are all the midpoint of $AB$, I now (and this is the part where I am not sure of) have proven that the $C'$ of ANY possible $C$ is the midpoint of $AB$, and therefore medians meet
EDIT: perhaps linear dependency is not the correct term, I meant that if I move C in a certain direction then the other points move linearly based on that, or in other words, for any point (say $E$) that is linearly dependent on $C$ there exists a 2x2 matrix that for any point $C''$ the matrix multiplied by $C''$ equals $E''$, which is the point that you get if you did all the projections and intersections with $C''$ instead of $C$. Please tell me if you have a better term.

What does it mean that fixed points are linearly dependent of everything? Linear dependence is discussed in the context of vectors, not points. If your fixed points $A$ and $B$ are to be understood as vectors $OA$ and $OB$, where $O$ is the origin, then $OA$ and $OB$ are linearly dependent iff the line $OA$ passes through $B$ or $OB$ passes through $A$.

perhaps linear dependency is not the correct term, I meant that if I move $C$ in a certain direction then the other points move linearly based on that, or in other words, any point linearly dependent on $C$ can be written as a 2x2 matrix multiplied by $C$ and when I move $C$ it will still hold @RandyMarsh

I would suggest you explain what you mean by linear dependence. Linear dependence is a common concept with a standard definition, but you seem to mean something else by it (maybe the property of being on the same line?). Maybe a concrete example would help clarify your post.

I am thinking of fixed points like you would think about paramaters in calculus, I could have decided $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(0,1)$. $C$ can be moved around, and when I move $C$ around, I claim it affects all the points and lines linearly.
